# Error in changing the background dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

First i've created a button(named as BackgroundChooser) that is used to change the background image dynamically(they can select their own image as background). But i have already used a default background image(image1.jpg) for my windows phone 7 application. When i click on the choose background button, it directs to our saved pictures. After that i have selected am image as my own background image. But the default background image is still doesn't changed. 
Then when i have changed the default background to black, then i can set my own background image(it's working perfectly). Need help!!! Thanks in advance for your hard work!!!

Below is the code i have used-:

```
    private void BackgroundChooser_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var PhotoChooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
        PhotoChooser.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult(PhotoChooser_Completed);
        PhotoChooser.Show();
    }

    void PhotoChooser_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                var app = Application.Current as App;
                if (app == null)
                return;
                var imageBrush = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = bmp, Opacity = 0.5d };
                app.RootFrame.Background = imageBrush;
                //app.RootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);  //we can apply just color too like this
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing this too, also didn't work. Curious to see if someone has the answer on this.

Comment: How and where are you setting the default background?

Answer (score 1):

instead of `app.RootFrame.Background`, try setting the Background property on some display object on your page such as `myPanoramaControl.Background = imageBrush;` or `LayoutRoot.Background = imageBrush;` (where LayoutRoot is the name of the default grid control for a new WP Page)

Comment: Hmm, I did see an example using app.RootFrame.Background so perhaps that is all fine and dandy. If that is the case, then I would think there is an issue with your `BitmapImage` obj. For fun, try setting `bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http:urlToAnImage", UriKind.Absolute))` and see if that does the trick