# Background image Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a little question, I want to change the background of my application with C#.
I tried this code :

```
var app = Application.Current as App;
var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
{
ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative))
};
app.RootFrame.Background = imageBrush;
```

But it doesn't work, the background is dark.. I tried to do :

```
app.RootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

And it works well. So I don't understand where is the problem, my image is 480*800 px and I set *Build Action* to *Content* and *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy if newer* .

Thanks for all

Comment: use imagebrush to set image as backgorund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try it

```
        var app = Application.Current as App;
        if (app == null)
            return;

        var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
        {
        };
        var uu = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative));
        uu.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        imageBrush.ImageSource = uu;

        app.RootFrame.Background = imageBrush;
```

Mark:           uu.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing almost the exact same thing successfully with an image, except I'm setting the image as the background to a panorama control. I know someone else had the same problem you did in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483812/error-in-changing-the-background-dynamically) so I suggested setting the background of the LayoutRoot or other control instead of the app.RootFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both !!

I had previously tried the two solutions separately and it didn't work. But together it works perfectly!

The code :

```
var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
{
};
var uu = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/image.png", UriKind.Relative));
uu.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
imageBrush.ImageSource = uu;

LayoutRoot.Background = imageBrush;
```